# Solving a third order polynomial matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I want to solve the following matrix equation with respect to the matrix variable $\mathbf{X}$ which is a real symmetric positive definite matrix. The given matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is real and symmetric, "a" is a scalar, and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix of the appropriate size.

$$\mathbf{X}^{-1}\mathbf{X}^{-1} + \big(\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{I}\big)^{-1} +a\mathbf{X}= \mathbf{A} $$

If we ignore the first term in this equation, there is a closed form solution in the following paper, eq. (14)  and Lemma 2.1 (I need a wise closed form solution like this one!)
http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2009/09/2409.pdf

Comment: Where is the scalar $a$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Your question is stated as an isolated problem with no context and doesn't show any effort of your own. As such, it is likely to attract down votes and get closed. Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3966669/edit) your question to make improvements. Have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to improve the quality of this and future posts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Try to show that if $A$ has the eigendecomposition $V\Lambda V^T$ then $X$ must have the eigendecomposition $VDV^T$ where $\Lambda = D^{-2}+(D-I)^{-1}-aD$. In other words, $X$ must have the same eigenvectors as $A$ and for each eigenpair $(\lambda,v)$ of $A$, we have that $(d,v)$ is an eigenpair of $D$ where $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{d^2}+\dfrac{1}{d-1}-ad$.

From there, you simply need to solve the equation $\lambda = \dfrac{1}{d^2}+\dfrac{1}{d-1}-ad$ for $d$ in terms of each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, this is the first thing that I can go for it and I did actually it but I can not find a solution there since it leads to a 4th order polynomial which is not easy to find a closed form solution at the end. To be more specific, for my original problem (which is big and complicated and I can not explain it here), I need a kind of closed form solution here, a wiser solution, e.g. the one that is proposed in the following paper (if we ignore the first term in the above equation)

http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2009/09/2409.pdf